# Stripe throws an Exception that I have already reached the limit of 16 test webhook endpoints

Tags: php, webhooks

But I have only added 3 endpoints. At the moment my site is not working, because it throws the above error. Is there a way to change the settings so that I can test my local-page. The Page is created from this [tutorial](https://www.codexworld.com/stripe-subscription-payment-integration-php/) [image: Screenshot of my Stripe Dashboard]

Comment: It shows exactly 16 lines there, so presumably stripe considers these different endpoints, despite the same URL being used multiple times. So you appear to _have_ added 16 webhook endpoints already. Go figure out how you can remove some of them again then …?

Comment: as @misorude writes: You have spent the 16 allowed, these are all considered separate webhook endpoints and are all called when the the events specified on them happens.

What are you trying to do, since you have so many webhooks pointing to the same url?

Comment: That was the problem thx